# ¿Alguna solución cuando el fragmento de código (code snippet) produce un resultado más grande que el espacio que lo muestra?

Tags: discusión

Hay fragmentos de código que poseen contenido largo y cuando se pulsa en ejecutar no se muestra todo lo que hay en la prueba, dado que el espacio no es tan grande.

Veamos un ejemplo, tomado de [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/232604/29967).

Se pulsa en `Ejecutar` y sólo aparece ...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

... pero hay más contenido en la prueba. Vamos a bajar...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vamos a verlo en página completa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando el usuario es nuevo quizá ni siquiera se dé cuenta de que hay más contenido. ¿Qué recomiendan para estos casos? ¿Hay alguna forma de dar más espacio al contenido de la prueba o de presentarla por defecto en pantalla completa o algo por el estilo?

Comment: Quizá en estos casos haya que especificar de manera clara que abra el resultado en pantalla completa.

Comment: En preguntas de shell scripting a veces pasa que el resultado es muy extenso. Para esos casos, yo tiendo a eliminar las líneas del medio y poner algo así como `....` para indicarlo. En un snippet no sé cuán posible es hacer algo así.

Comment: @lois6b ¿cómo se especifica que abra el resultado en pantalla completa?

Comment: @fedorqui podría ser una posibilidad poner dos elementos de cada parte de la lista, pero en este caso concreto no se gana mucho debido sobre todo al vídeo que aparece abajo, aparte de que se trunca el código original. De todos modos a mi me gusta responder usando el código completo que se ha compartido en estos casos.

Comment: @A.Cedano con un texto en negrita heheh

Comment: @lois6b me refería y si en la configuración del snippet no es posible hacerlo, para que se abra en pantalla grande cuando se pulse en `Ejecutar` ¿?

Comment: Talvés no logro comprender del todo tu inquietud, pero, ¿no para eso está el scroll del snippet?

Comment: @Phi ... *Cuando el usuario es nuevo quizá ni siquiera se dé cuenta de que hay más contenido.*  El scroll no es evidente, ni siquiera se activa cuando te colocas sobre los resultados con el ratón.

Comment: ¿Qué navegador usas? En tu imagen no se nota el scroll ([acá sí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKntn.png)) pero eso ya no es temática del sitio, si alguien ve un scroll en algún momento se dará cuenta que hay más contenido, independientemente si está navegando en [es.so] o cualquer otra página

Comment: @Phi, uso Safari y el scroll no es tan evidente... se activa únicamente si estoy en el área donde se muestra el snippet y como el touchpad o muevo el ratón, y si dejo de moverme por el área desaparece. De hecho quise hacer una captura de pantalla mostrando el scroll y fue imposible porque precisamente desaparece.

Comment: En este caso son espacios. Hay que editar la publicación quitando esos espacios que sobran. Además en otros casos los snippets usan tabuladores de 8 caracteres, en este caso recomiendo reemplazar cada tabulador por 2 caracteres.

Comment: Ah, perdón, acabo de notar que no era sobre el código si no por el alto del resultado de ejecutar el snippet. Sin embargo lo que dije podría servir de algo.